# Where is the ear file located, when deployed to Jboss

Tags: file, deployment, jboss, ear

Ear file was deployed on Jboss (wildfly 8.1, if it matters)
I need to investigate what version of the ear file it is, and the name does not have it.  So, need to look into ear's manifest file.  (I know version is there).
But, I do not know where the ear is located under JBOSS folder structure ?
Can anyone help ?
..\JBOSSHOME\domain\servers\MyServerName ?? what else ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is deployed under the **content** folder of your server. But it will be respecting he hash of it and the name.ear has been renamed as content. With WildFly > 14 you can use exploded deployments and read the deployment content directly from the jboss cli.